# Include count of one-to-many relation in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
users
+----------+----------+----------+
| id       | name     | dob      |
+----------+----------+----------+

authentications
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| id       | user_id  | provider |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

A user, has-many authentications. `user_id` in the `authentications` table is a foreign key to the `users` table.

Im trying to comple the following output:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+ 
|    user.id    |   user.name   |   user.dob    |       C       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Here, C is, the count of the users authentications where provider is 'facebook'. If instead of the count, I could get a boolean value, ie true if authentications are present, false if not, that would be even better.

I cant figure how to go about constructing the query. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: what type of sql are you using?

Comment: If you mean what database, Im using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This will return the actual count of Authorization of type FB for every user :

`

```
Select Name UserName, ID UserID, COUNT(FBAuth) FBAuthCount
from Users LEFT JOIN
(Select UserID, COUNT(AuthType) FBAuth from Auth 
Where AuthType = 'FB'
Group by USERID) Auths on (Users.ID = Auths.UserId)
Group by ID, Name
```

`

2) This will return the flag true or false for every user depending on thier authorization type:

`

```
Select Name UserName, ID UserID, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(FBAuth) > 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END FBAuthFLAG
from Users LEFT JOIN 
(Select UserID, COUNT(AuthType) FBAuth from Auth 
Where AuthType = 'FB'
Group by USERID) Auths on (Users.ID = Auths.UserId)
Group by ID, Name
```

`

Using a join on smaller dataset: faster response.
Finally, I believe this is the one:

`

```
SELECT users.id,
       users.email,
       users.name,
       users.sid,
       users.created_at,
       ( CASE
           WHEN fb_auth > 0
           THEN 'true'
           ELSE 'false'
         END ) AS facebook
FROM   users
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT authentications.user_id,
                         Count(authentications.provider) fb_auth
                  FROM   authentications
                  WHERE  provider = 'facebook'
                  GROUP  BY user_id) auths
              ON ( users.id = auths.user_id )
GROUP  BY users.id,
          users.email,
          users.name,
          users.sid,
          users.created_at
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Create your query with your JOIN between users and authentications, and add in a GROUP BY on the User Id field first. Your group by will need to contain subsequent fields that you wish to list in your results although they won't change the effect of the results:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.dob, COUNT(a.user_id) as authCount
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN authentications a on u.id = a.user_id
WHERE a.provider = 'facebook'
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.dob
```

Comment: This only returns results for users where the count is > 0. I need results for all users.

Comment: Sorry about that. Change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and that should include everything

Answer (score 0):

C is the count, B will return 1 if there is a facebook provider and 0 if not (boolean).  Updated to use LEFT OUTER JOIN so that all users are included.

```
SELECT 
   users.id,
   users.name,
   users.DOB,
   SUM(CASE WHEN authentications.provider = 'facebook' then 1 else 0 end) as C,
   MAX(CASE WHEN authentications.provider = 'facebook' then 1 else 0 end) as B
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN authentications
   ON users.id = authentications.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name, users.DOB
```

Comment: Is this query expected to be VERY, VERY, VERY, slow? My system hangs, even when I run this with a limit of 5.

Comment: depends on many variables such as your system, the number of rows in the tables, the indexes, etc...

Answer (score -1):

The earlier answers worked, but were extremely slow. The query used to take 15-20 minutes, to run. This one, suggested by a friend runs much faster (~4s for the same dataset).

```
SELECT users.id,
       users.email,
       users.name,
       users.sid,
       users.created_at,
       ( CASE
           WHEN fb_auth > 0
           THEN 'true'
           ELSE 'false'
         END ) AS facebook
FROM   users
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT authentications.user_id,
                         Count(authentications.provider) fb_auth
                  FROM   authentications
                  WHERE  provider = 'facebook'
                  GROUP  BY user_id) auths
              ON ( users.id = auths.user_id )
GROUP  BY users.id,
          users.email,
          users.name,
          users.sid,
          users.created_at;
```